# How can I mount an aws linux instance locally?

Tags: mount-point

I work on a windows machine but I ssh into an AWS linux box to do most of my work. I'm trying to figure out a way I can use my local tools (specifically Spyder) to open up files (python files) from the server so I can edit them in the IDE and then run them on the server. (Note: its not just for code, I also want to be able to open csv's I generate, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Many modern IDE's provide this option through SSH, looking at the documentation for Spyder, it seems to refer to this configuration as a 'remote kernel'.

I do not use Spyder, but I use a similar configuration to do development with Visual Studio Code on my laptop with remote execution over SSH to an EC2 instance.  In VS Code it is referred to as Remote SSH, you open a folder on the remote server as your VS Code workspace.